How to create a Python PIP package on the fly?
I have some folders with Python code (about 1000) — and I want to make a PIP package from each one (from Python script).
In this script I want to set the following:

package name;
package version;
requirements info;
subpackages;
extra files.

Is there any good way to do it either than making a copy of each directory, writing there setup.py, MANIFEST.in and setup.cfg — and running os.system("python3 sdist upload -r local") ?

Why copy these directories? What's wrong with having setuptools files in each permanently?
